# Sequence contains several elements Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, select, dapper

I'm using Dapper for retrieve a result of my request SELECT.

```
 List<dynamic> results = connection.Query("SELECT id_fonction from liste_personnels_fonctions where id_personnel = @id_personnel", new { id_personnel }).ToList();
```

But sometimes I have 2 results. When I use `.SingleOrDefault()` I have an exception : "Sequence contains several elements" when I have more than one row returned. When I use `FirstOrDefault` I have only first row and I need both of them... 
So what can I do? I try with List<> and var[] to retrieve the results but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` throws an exception if there is more than 1. That is by design. if you want the first use `FirstOrDefault`. If you need (up to) two of them use `Take(2).ToList()`. If you need all use `ToList()`.

Comment: Hmm, but now I don't know how to retrieve this result into the List<int>. I have :  List<dynamic> results = connection.Query("SELECT id_fonction from liste_personnels_fonctions where id_personnel = @id_personnel", new { id_personnel }).ToList();
                List<int> fonctions = new List<int>();

                foreach (dynamic r in results)
                {
                    var func = (int)r?.func;
                    fonctions.Add(func);
                }  and an exception when I do var func = (int)r?.func;

Comment: My result is  : {{DapperRow, id_fonction = '10'}} and {{DapperRow, id_fonction = '8'}} and I need only List<int> {10, 8} (sorry I don't know how to explain

Comment: and when I do : fonctions = results.Select(z => z.id_personnel ).ToList(); then fonctions = {null, null}

Comment: `Select(z => z.id_fonction).ToList()` because `id_fonction` is the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just a list of Int then ask Dapper for that

```
List<int> results = connection.Query<int>("SELECT id_fonction from liste_personnels_fonctions where id_personnel = @id_personnel", new { id_personnel }).ToList();
```